# Spring Boot onApplicationEvent(ContextClosedEvent event) not called on in case of exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Below is the sample code , i.e

```
@Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments applicationArguments) throws Exception {
        log.info("Starting...");
        mainThread.start();
        mainThread.join();
        log.info("Exiting...");
    }

    @EventListener
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextClosedEvent event) {
        log.info("Inside on ApplicationEvent");
        mainThread.interrupt();
        log.info("Thread Interupted");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            someAppLogic.doLogic();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e instanceof  InterruptedException || e.getCause() instanceof InterruptedException) {
                log.info("Interrupted...");
            } else {
                log.error("Exception occurred", e);
                exitCode = 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

1. someAppLogic.doLogic(); get called in mainThread on Spring Boot Application start
2. The goal is to have mainThread interrupt in the method on ApplicationEvent in case of exception
   in the someAppLogic.doLogic(); and have an exitcode as 1.

But the issue is **main.interrupt() inside onApplicationEvent never gets** called ***in case of exception
from the run method i.e when someAppLogic.doLogic() throws an exception.***

This Spring boot application is going to be deployed in Kubernetes so pod containing this should gracefully shutdown .

SO the question is
How to handle any exception thrown by someAppLogic.doLogic(); gracefully  and send exitcode as 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke close() on ConfigurableApplicationContext for ContextClosedEvent to be published.

```
    //you need to figure out how to get hold of this object
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            someAppLogic.doLogic();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e instanceof  InterruptedException || e.getCause() instanceof InterruptedException) {
                log.info("Interrupted...");
            } else {
                log.error("Exception occurred", e);
                exitCode = 1;
                //call close
                context.close();
            }
        }
    }
```